# NuGet package Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact does not copy native DLLs

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, sql-server-ce, c#-native-library

I have created a .NET Framework 4.8 C# Class Library project that uses x64 as the TargetFramework.

I have added the NuGet package [Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact/) to the project.
When I build the project, only the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll file, which sits flat in the \lib\net40 folder, is copied to the Output folder.

**The files that are in the NativeBinaries\amd64\ directory of the NuGet package are not copied.**

But I need them in the OutputPath\amd64 directory.
What settings do I need to make so that these files are also copied?

**Edit**

Here is the content of my csproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{409AD54E-75FD-419F-B5D7-D2368105B4A8}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>NuGetSQLTestClassLibraryNetFramework</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>NuGetSQLTestClassLibraryNetFramework</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact">
      <Version>4.0.8876.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you using a classic project type? Otherwise you must fix manually

Comment: @ErikEJ Yes, I'm using a classic project type: <Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

Comment: You can just include the files as Content, Copy always

Comment: Hi @ErikEJ Can you a little more precise. Do I have to modify the NuGet package? Or how can I add the files to the output directory if they are "only" present in the NuGet package?

Comment: Something like this: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2013/10/sql-server-compact-4-desktop-app-with.html?m=1

Comment: Hi @ErikEJ thanks for the reply. I don't find this very helpful for two reasons:1. Linked answers are always bad. If your page goes offline, the answer is lost. 2. about the answer itself: it describes how to insert the DLLs manually into a project. But that was not my question. I want to use the NuGet package and the native DLLs are not copied to the bin (sub) folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my side, it works well and I have `OutputPath\amd64` directory with the nuget package.

[image]

So please try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

**1)** [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) first or just delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`

**Also**, delete the `packages` folder under `<solution_folder>`.

**2)** run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

**Update**

**Since** you have used [PackageReference nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) and you cannot get what you want in that format since the author did not consider the compatibility of PackageReference with the nuget package.

**In my side**, I used `packages.config` nuget management format and then get that.

To get what you want, you should add these additionally:

**1)** add this `<GeneratePathProperty>true</GeneratePathProperty>`under that nuget package reference node to generate msbuild property called `PkgMicrosoft_SqlServer_Compact` about the content path of the nupkg.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact">
      <Version>4.0.8876.1</Version>
      <GeneratePathProperty>true</GeneratePathProperty>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**2)** right-click on the Proeject Properties-->Build Events-->post-build event command line--> add these:

```
 if not exist "$(TargetDir)x86" md "$(TargetDir)x86"
    xcopy /s /y "$(PkgMicrosoft_SqlServer_Compact)\NativeBinaries\x86\*.*" "$(TargetDir)x86"
    if not exist "$(TargetDir)amd64" md "$(TargetDir)amd64"
    xcopy /s /y "$(PkgMicrosoft_SqlServer_Compact)\NativeBinaries\amd64\*.*" "$(TargetDir)amd64"
```

**After that**, rebuild to get what you want.

Comment: Hi @sara-liu-msft: Good to see that in principle it should work. For better understanding, I have added the contents of my csproj file in my original question. My output folder unfortunately still contains only System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: Ohh. You have used PackageReference nuget package management format and that format cannot get that. Since the author of the nuget package does not consider the compatibility of packagereference and the nuget package. I used packages.config nuget management format. I have updated my answer and you can check it.